# No Subset of a Path is open

Tags: calculus, analysis

Let $\gamma:[a,b]\subset\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ be continously differentiable. Prove that no subset $A\subset \gamma([a,b])$ is open in $\mathbb{C}$. And would this also be true if $\gamma$ is just continuous?

Comment: Prove by contradiction.what about peano curves?

Comment: Your avatar sorta looks like a [space filling curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve)......

Comment: I thought about using the theorem that says that every preimage of an open set is open iff the function is continous, but in that theorem open means open in the domain/codomain. Therefore that doesn't lead to a contradiction because the preimage can easily be open in $[a,b]$ although it won't be open in $\mathbb{C}$.